# Hook to change HTTP response headers

Tags: headers

I want to write a simple Wordpress plugin.  The plugin will:

1. Read (if set) a cookie from the visitor
2. Send a cookie (if not set) to the visitor
3. Depending on the cookie value I will redirect the user to a new pages

I found some documentation for getting/setting cookies through WP, and I'm guessing I can just issue a redirect from PHP.  So I downloaded the WordPress Boilerplate (WPBP) code and so far so good.  But I'm stuck at:

1. Which WP callback should I hook into for my code?  (init ?)  I found the plugin documentation but I'm struggling to understand where this type of code should hook into.
2. Should I put any of my code into the main/global portion of the WPBP file?  Or only in the called back function.
3. This plugin will run on a WP multisite installation.  Does that mean my plugin code would run on every site?  If so, how could I restrict my plugin code to run on only a particular site?  (PHP check for a URI?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions about how you should structure your plugin are somewhat too broad, but here is a specific answer to the title question.

To change headers before they’re sent, use the `wp_headers` filter.

```
function tsg_filter_headers( $headers ) 
{
    // For debug. This will break your page but you will see which headers are sent
    // print_r( $headers );

    // It’s a good idea to leave the admin alone
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        // Add or redefine 'Content-Location' header
        $headers['Content-Location'] = '/my-receipts/42';
    }

    return $headers;     
}
add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'tsg_filter_headers' );
```

See the WordPress doc [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/).

Comment: Great thanks - and I'll split my question above